# C++ keypress: getch, cin.get?

Tags: c++, keypress

I have a Win32 program that runs on a loop. I would like to be able to pause that program while awaiting a keypress. It doesn't matter whether I use 'any key' or a specific key, but I need to have the program freeze until I press something.

I am wondering which command I should use. I am working with Visual C++ and the compiler doesn't recognise any of the following commands:

```
cin.get()

std::cin.get()

getch()
```

I am relatively new to C++. I understand that in a console app this is a fairly simple action to take (cin.get), but that it can be more difficult in Win32. Any simple solution or workaround would be appreciated. The program is bespoke to be used in a single scientific experiment, so for now I'm not fussed if the solution is a little botchy(!)

Apologies if I've missed any important info from my question.

Comment: `cin.get()` and `std::cin.get()` are same!

Comment: What headers have you included? `std::cin` needs `#include <iostream>`. `_getch` requires `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: Is your program a console or a GUI app?

Comment: When I'm writing a console program in Windows, I just use system("pause");

Comment: Why do you need to pause, exactly? The thing about a Windows program is that it sits there doing nothing in particular (but pumping messages) until it has something to do. Pausing would stop the message pump and not allow people to resize the window etc until a key was pressed. That's not normal Windows behaviour.

Comment: There's a loop running that works with an eye tracking device. The system triggers external devices when the eyes are in a given position. I want the external event to only trigger once when the eyes are pointing in the given direction, until I am ready for the event to be triggered again. The Windows program still runs - I just don't want the loop to continue until I am ready

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You should use neither.

You should use

```
#include <iostream>
...
int main()
{
   ... 
   std::cin.ignore(); //why read something if you need to ignore it? :)
}'
```

[Here's the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Comment: I like this because it's C++, not C, it doesn't require declaring some variable you're never going to use, and it's clear about your intent.

Comment: BTW, for me this is working as "Press enter to exit", not "Press any key to exit". I.e. I can press space, or any other keys, but it does not do anything until Enter is then pressed. (A C++ linux console application.)

Comment: @DarrenCook getting keyboard input without pressing enter is really really annoying and there is no portable way to do it. If you want to, you need input handling libraries, which seem overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score 8):

Example:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Press any key to continue . . ." << std::endl;
  _getch(); // wait for keypress
}
```

`_getch()` is C++ equivalent to C `getch()`

Comment: +1 for portable way of actually getting a char and not a line. But unfortunately that produces a return value ignored warning but otherwise ok.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char temp;
cin >> temp;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's "press any key, then press enter".

Comment: This can be used in a Win32 GUI app?

Comment: It seems I can't add <iostream> to my code. It throws up all sorts of errors before I even add anything post pre-compiler

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are looking for an alternative for getch ( which does not echo to screen).

If you are using windows and visual studio to be precise try using _getch.
Here is a link to it 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks very much. This has compiled and I'll take it to the lab to try it out! Purely out of interest, does anyone know the reason why a comamnd like getch() would be depracated and then replaced with _getch()? Seems an unnecessary complication (to a noob)

Comment: Probably because it is not portable and the rename indicates that implicitly by the '_'.

Answer (score 1):

You should `#include <iostream>` and use `std::cin.get();`

I think the `getch()` is a C function, but since you are using C++, then the `cin` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score -4):

```
HWND hwnd = ::GetConsoleWindow();

while (!((::GetForegroundWindow() == hwnd) &&
        ((::GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000) != 0)))
    ::Sleep(0);
```

Suppose it is not the best way but it solved my problem.
Replace VK_SPACE with any other value you like.
And it is not portable.

Comment: Such infinile loop will eat all process time. Never use it in real projects.

Comment: @dmitry-sazonov, you are right. I've missed that if there is no other threads in the process Sleep will return immediately. I guess explicit time out would make this code little bit better. But still should not be used in real projects.