# Trying to count all the prime numbers but my output is crazy

Tags: primes, counting

```
    #include <iostream> 
    using namespace std;



    int main () 
    {
       int count = 0;

          for (int x=2; x < 100; x++)

              for (int y=2; y < x; y++)
              {

                 if (x % y == 0) 
                 break;
                 else if (x == y + 1)
                      count++;
                      cout << x << " ";

       cout << count;
       system("pause")
       return 0;




    }
```

I want to print the prime numbers and also print out the number of prime numbers between 2 and 100. which should be 24. Instead I get a ton of repeats of the prime numbers and then the number 24. I'm sure it's a logical error, just not catching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are syntax errors.

Second, always use curly braces with `if/else` unless you know what you are doing - there's an error related to this.

Third, using `system()` requires `#include <cstdlib>`. Your compiler is lax if it allows you to not to (`g++` doesn't).

Fourth, `pause` is not a standalone program but a `cmd.exe` builtin so `system()` may fail depending on the compiler/environment used. A neater way is [C++ keypress: getch, cin.get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010760/c-keypress-getch-cin-get) .

Finally, your algorithm is highly suboptimal. E.g. `y` only needs to go up to `x/2+1` and it's reasonable to store the primes already found in an array/list and try only them.

Comment: Compiling it is not the problem it runs fine I just want to to be able to count the primes numbers as the elseif statement catches them and then print out the total