# Any Idea why this if statment isn't working?

Tags: c++

I know it's probably a simply mistake, but I am rather new at this. Any idea why this might not be working.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
   float x, y;
   cout << "Please enter the miles traveled:", x;
   cin >> x;

   if (x <= 0)
      cout << "Invalid number please try again.";

   if (x > 1) {
      y = ((x * .75) + 2);
      cprintf("Your total amount owed is $%.2f"), y;
   }

   getch();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". Your computer exploded? The code doesn't compile? The code doesn't produce the expected output with a certain input?

Comment: Can you tell us your specific problem with that code? Do you get some errors?

Comment: What isn't working?  What are your inputs?  What is your output?

Comment: You have syntax errors in your program cprintf("Your total amount owed is $%.2f"), y;

Comment: My cprintf statement is not outputting the equation that I have in the line.

Answer (score 4):

First, you have some minor mistakes in your program.

- In the line

  ```
  cprintf("Your total amount owed is $%.2f"), y;
  ```

  you should put the `y` inside the function call, i.e.

  ```
  cprintf("Your total amount owed is $%.2f", y);
  ```
- Also, the `, x` in the line

  ```
  cout<< "Please enter the miles traveled:", x;
  ```

  should be removed. Both `, x` and `, y` in the above quoted lines have no effect at all.
- Then, you should add the return type `int` to your `main()` function:

  ```
  int main() {
      ... 
  }
  ```
- Finally, since you are using `cin` and `cout` from the namespace `std`, you should either write `std::cin` and `std::cout` respectively, or put a `using namespace std;` after your includes, or put `using std::cin;` and `using std::cout;` after the includes (the last option is recommended).
- You also shouldn't `#include <iostream.h>` (I don't know that one, it is non-standard) but rather `<iostream>`, and I guess if you change that, explicitly mentioning the namespace, like in the above point, is then required.

So far, the program should "work", but I guess not in the way you want it to behave. You probably want the program to **repeat** after the user made an input error. For this, you should use a **loop**. Something like this should do the job:

```
cin >> x;
while (x <= 0)
{
    cout << "Invalid number please try again.";
    cin >> x;
}
```

Also, what should your program do if the user enters a number between 0 and 1? I guess instead of `x > 1` you want `x > 0`, i.e. just the opposite of the "error case" `x <= 0`. This is usually expressed with an `else` block. But if you write a loop repeating until the user entered a positive `x`, you can be sure that it is really positive **after** the loop.

Comment: main too doesn't have a return type, while he is returning 0 from his code.

Comment: @Tejendra Thanks, added it to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. When declaring or defining a function it's required to have a type, be it `void` or `auto` while `auto` is, strictly-speaking, no type. A strictly-conforming `main` function is `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)`.
2. This line

   ```
   cout<< "Please enter the miles traveled:", x;
   ```

   looks dubious. What's the `x` supposed to do here? Remove the `, x` part.
3. This line

   ```
    cprintf("Your total amount owed is $%.2f"), y;
   ```

   is bad. Pass `y` inside the parantheses, like

   ```
   cprintf("Your total amount owed is $%.2f", y);
   ```
4. `cout` etc. are from the `std` namespace. Either add a `std::` before all of them or put a `using namespace std;` before `main`.
5. This line

   ```
   y=((x*.75)+2);
   ```

   isn't necessarily wrong but it multiplies a `float` with a `double`, killing off precision. Use `.75f` instead.
6. `float y` is only used in one `if`-clause, so narrow down its scope to that.
7. `<iostream.h>` isn't guaranteed to exist by the C++ standard. It's `<iostream>`.
8. Remove that `<conio.h>` inclusion. That's wicked because non-standard! Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010760/c-keypress-getch-cin-get) instead.
9. Proceeding with the 8<sup>th</sup> point, don't use all that non-standard C-ish crap. C++ **is not** C!

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
```

you haven't mentioned return type of main()

```
cprintf("Your total amount owed is $%.2f", y);
```

remove

```
getch()
```

and

```
cout<< "Please enter the miles traveled: " << x;
```

**EDIT**

Also with gcc you cannot use `conio.h`

Comment: there are a lot of mistakes in this program apart from this.

Answer (score 1):

**main**, being a function, needs to return type int (void too will work in some systems). The x and the y following the cout/cprintf statements, should be removed. You may also want to enclose the content of the first **if** statement into a while loop, until the desired condition becomes true.

```
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x, y;
    cout << "Please enter the miles traveled: ";
    cin >> x;

    while (x <= 0.f) {
        cout << "Invalid number please try again.";
        cin >> x;
    }

    y = ((x*.75) + 2);
    cout << "Your total amount owed is : " << y;    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main` is __not__ allowed to return `void`. Not even in C.

Comment: Also, you have an infinite loop.