# Exiting a "do while" by pressing any key without hitting enter?

Tags: c++, while-loop

Having issues with my code not working. I'm trying to get it to exit the do while by pressing any key on the keyboard but without hitting enter. My code snippet is below.

```
void LemonadeBuyANDCheck()
{
    int iCupsToBuy = rand() % (MAX_CUPS - MIN_CUPS) + MIN_CUPS;


    bool continueLoop = true;
    do 
    {
        int Userinput = 1;
        Userinput = !_kbhit();
        fflush(stdin);

        if (Userinput == 1)
        {
            continueLoop = false;
        }

        StoreIsOpen();
        int randomNumber = rand() % 100;

        if (iCupsOfLemonadeInStock == 0)
        {
            cout << "Customer came to buy some lemonade but you didnt have any in stock :(\n";
            //continueLoop = false;
        }

        else if (randomNumber <= 25)
        {

            cout << "Wow your lemonade is way too expensive!\n";
            iCustomerCounter++;

        }

        else if (randomNumber >= 75)
        {

            cout << "Eww your recipe for lemonade... Wow..\n";
            iCustomerCounter++;
        }


        else if (iCupsOfLemonadeInStock >= iCupsToBuy)
        {

            cout << "You sold " << iCupsToBuy << "cups of lemonade!\n";

            iCupsOfLemonadeInStock = iCupsOfLemonadeInStock - iCupsToBuy;
            iCupsOfLemonadeSold = iCupsOfLemonadeSold - iCupsToBuy;
            //Money

            fMoneyEarned += (iCupsToBuy * fCurrentLemonadePrice);
            fCurrentMoney += (iCupsToBuy * fCurrentLemonadePrice);

            iCustomerCounter++;
        }
        else if (iCupsOfLemonadeInStock < iCupsToBuy)
        {
            cout << "You didnt have enough lemonade in stock so you only sold " << iCupsToBuy - iCupsOfLemonadeInStock << endl;

            fMoneyEarned += (iCupsOfLemonadeInStock * fCurrentLemonadePrice);
            fCurrentMoney += (iCupsOfLemonadeInStock * fCurrentLemonadePrice);
            iCupsOfLemonadeInStock = 0;

            iCustomerCounter++;
        }
    } while (continueLoop != true);
    fflush(stdin);
        GameMenuSelectionVerifier();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for an answer? First hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010760/c-keypress-getch-cin-get

Comment: what issues do you have?

Comment: The C++ standard library doesn't provide the "check for keypress" functionality, but you can use a library such as ncurses.

Comment: The Userinput kbhit and the while at the bottom dont work, when I press 1 its meant to exit the do while

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a function named "kbhit", it's in the "conio.h" header file. You can click [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html) for details. And you can modify it like this:

```
while(!kbhit());
```

Comment: And where would we get this "conio.h" header file? What if we want to write an application *without* dusting off our old 16-bit MS-DOS computer?

Comment: The "conio.h" header file is common, it's just like "stdio.h" header file. You just need write " #include <conio.h>" , and the computer will find it. Then you can use the kbhit function.

Comment: Common? Hah! It hasn't been common for over 20 years. May I borrow your time machine?

Comment: Perhaps Turbo C has that file. However, modern compilers (even going back to the 2000-2005) don't have that file. It is not even supported anymore on Windows.